# Split text in column into two separate columns

Tags: excel, split, vba

I am having trouble splitting the text on the Location into two separate columns based on the "-".  The code needs to loop through each row and split the cell values.

**Code:**

```
'Split Location into 2 Columns
    txt = Sheet4.Cells(i, 10).Value
    Location = Split(txt, "-")

    For i = 2 To LastRow2
        For j = 0 To UBound(Location)
            Cells(1, j + 1).Value = Location(j)
        Next j
    Next i
```

**Sample Sheet:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below assumes the data you want to manipulate is on your active sheet and you want to split the data on your current sheet and place it into column K.

I would use TextToColumns instead of a loop

```
Range("J2:J" & LastRow2).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J2"), _
                                       OtherChar:="-", _
                                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
```

If you want to use a loop you can include the txt / location variables inside the loop and use i / j as offsets for data placement

```
For i = 2 To LastRow2
    'Split Location into 2 Columns
    txt = Cells(i, 10).Value
    Location = Split(txt, "-")

    For j = 0 To UBound(Location)
        Cells(i, 10 + j).Value = Location(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just the `Sheet4.Cells(i, 10).Value` that you put outside the loop. Try something like this:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow2
    'Split Location into 2 Columns
    txt = Sheet4.Cells(i, 10).Value
    Location = Split(txt, "-")

    For j = 0 To UBound(Location)
        Cells(1, j + 1).Value = Location(j)
    Next j
Next i
```